# <span> css multiple css class - hierarchy

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<span class="tabs-fadding-number"></span>` that have the following properties : :

```
.tabs-fadding-number {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 40%;
    top: -12px;
}
```

Now using Javascript I add another class to that span `<span class="tabs-fadding-number add"></span>` :

```
.tabs-fadding-number .add {
    color: #357ae8;
}
```

However my css rules is not applied. How can I have a child .add css class, that is only applicable to .tabs-fadding-number class elements ?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the space: `.tabs-fadding-number.add`

Comment: You don't want the space in the css. Should look like `.tabs-fadding-number.add`

Comment: Go read up on the basics of CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between the class names.

```
.tabs-fadding-number.add {
    color: #357ae8;
}
```

Otherwise, what you're doing is finding elements with `.add` that is within `.tabs-fadding-number` as a parent.

Comment: This doesn't honor his desired constraint at the end of his question.

Comment: + 1 Thanks !! Your last statement clarify what I was doing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just look up in Chrome Developer. It's something like this

```
span.tabs-fadding-number.add
```